# How to modify the first letter of each word in a string using javascript while keeping inner HTML intact?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code looks at any element with the "title-case" class and modifies the first letter of each word to be slightly bigger IF it is an uppercase letter. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title-case').each(function(){
        $(this).html( capitalize_first_letter( $(this).html() ) );
    });
});

function capitalize_first_letter( str ) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
        var first_letter = this.substring(0,1);
        html += ( first_letter == first_letter.toUpperCase() ? '<span class="first-letter">'+first_letter+'</span>' : first_letter )+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    return html;
}
```

You can see it run here: http://jsfiddle.net/82Ebt/

It works for the most part but as you can see from the example it will break the inner HTML nodes. I'm actually at a loss as to how to tackle this and could use some ideas. I figured maybe manipulating just the .text() instead of .html() but that strips out the HTML outright.

Edit: I would like to point out that the reason I use javascript is because I would like every word in the string to have it's first letter bigger IF it is capitalized. The :first-letter pseudo-class only affects the first word.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work, at least in modern browsers -- use `.html()` with a callback and `.replace()` with a regex to detect only initial capital letters:

```
$('.title-case').html(function(i,el) {
    return el.replace(/\b([A-Z])/g, "<span class=\"first-letter\">$1</span>");
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/82Ebt/4/

Comment: Your solution works, because all tags are started with small-letters.If the OP will want to do replacements, which will be started with small-letters, then your solution won't work.

Comment: @Engineer An improved regex should be able to solve that, if it becomes an issue down the road.

Comment: The improvement will be very complicated,I guess.

Comment: @Engineer Not necessarily. But for now, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You could use CSS:</strike> It only affects first word

http://jsfiddle.net/82Ebt/1/

```
.title-case {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.title-case:first-letter {
    font-size: 115%;
}
```

Works in IE7+ (i don't have IE6) and i'd be surprised if any of the other common browsers didn't support it

Comment: IE6 share = 0.4% which are: 1% a man up there in the hill - 99% programmers :D

Comment: I just don't have it, so I couldn't test it. I have no idea if it works in IE6. If it doesn't, it would be worth bypassing javascript anyway in the browsers that did support it.

Comment: I really wished that there was a CSS-only solution to this but my script capitalizes the first letter of *every* word in the string. I scoured the web for a CSS only solution but every solution I found pointed towards javascript >:(

Comment: If you're genuinely worried about how an initial capital letter will look like in 0.4% of all browsers, you're doing something wrong in your job.

Comment: @Blazemonger True, but the issue is that this css solution doesn't capitalize *every word*, only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method: Its working for me.

```
    function capitalise(text) {

    var split = text.split(" "),
    res = [],
    i,
    len,
    component;

    $(split).each(function (index, element) {

        component = (element + "").trim();
        var first = component.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        var remain = component.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        res.push(first);
        res.push(remain);
        res.push(" "); 

    });

    return res.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $('.title-case').children().andSelf().each(function(){
     $(this).html( capitalize_first_letter( $(this).text() ) );
 });

 function capitalize_first_letter( str ) {    
    return str.replace(/\b[A-Z]/g,'<span class="first-letter">$&</span>');    
 }​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qm7wV/)